# Pure JS : push 2000++ characters asynchronously to server and get response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, large-data

would be grateful for some advice on the following. Using pure JS how could I asynchronously get the body of the current webpage (needs to handle 2000++ characters) and send the 'content' to a remote server, wait for the response and do something with the response (most likely a json array of data)

The main thing here im trying to get over is the 2000 character limit in urls imposed by the browser.

Pure JS solutions only please.

Many thanks.

Comment: AJAX POST request will work fine.

Comment: 2000 characters is not [tag:large-data]! Did you experience any problems with a standard approach?

Comment: @Brad AJAX POST doesnt work fine. The content always gets truncated for me.

Comment: @Bergi I appreciate large-data is a bit misleading but it is subjective to the context. My point is that I need to be able to consume much larger amounts of data in my 'slurp' than GET allows you to handle (circa 2000 chars) and I have not found that AJAX POST works either.

Comment: @Orcra You can POST whatever size you want.  You're probably not using POST, you're probably using GET and putting your data in the query string.  Can't help you anyway since you didn't show us your code...

Comment: @Brad  good point about the code. I will put something up.